# Golang binary built inside Docker container, still Mach-O executable format?

Tags: macos, go, docker, boot2docker, docker-machine

I could really use some help here. What I am trying to do is use the standard golang:1.5 Docker image to build a Go binary, then copy that binary out of the container and into a new minimal Docker container based on busybox. The binary is pulled out of the container using a Docker mounted volume. There are two problems so far that I have run into.

1. The resulting binary on the host (and subsequently copied into the second container) still seems to be a Mach-O 64-bit executable when running the `file` command. Is the Docker container somehow getting GOOS and GOARCH from the host?
2. When manually running the container with `bash` and building the Go binary, it now says it is an ELF executable but it is dynamically linked. I thought by default built statically linked binaries? I could just be wrong in this assumption.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

EDIT: Here are the commands I am using. Hopefully this makes it a bit more clear

```
## golang:1.5 base image with WORKDIR set to $GOPATH/src/myproject the source
## for the project was added in when creating the 'mybuild_img' docker image
## GOPATH is set automatically in the golang image.
docker run -i -v `pwd`/jenkins/out:$GOPATH/src/myproject/jenkins/out mybuild_img:latest bash -c 'go build && cp myproject ./jenkins/out'
```

Once the container is done running I have a Mach-O 64-bit executable in ./jenkins/out/. I'm not sure if this is some kind of weird behavior with docker-machine/boot2docker or anything like that. Just seems really weird. I have confirmed that if i set `GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64` before the `go build` command, then I do get an executable of the correct type. Just trying to figure out what is going on here.

Comment: did you check and ensure that GOPATH is set right in the container?  you may be seeing a OSX compiled version from your mac into the container if GOPATH isn't set.  look in the dir of the package you are explicitly compiling, see if binary is there.  maybe a simple -o /binname will work

Comment: You're going to have to show the steps you're using to do this, because it doesn't really make sense. Re #2, binaries are only static by default if there's no cgo, and the stdlib links to libc for name resolution and user lookup.

Comment: Added an edit including the docker build command, hopefully it helps and doesn't make it more confusing.

Comment: docker-machine is running a Linux host, and environment variables aren't transferred. Have you just printed out GOOS and GOARCH from within the container to make sure you haven't set those somewhere? (`docker run mybuild_img:latest go env`)

Comment: i didn't think to print the `go env` but i did add `&& echo $GOARCH && echo $GOOS` at the beginning of the command and they were unset (before explicitly adding them in the workaround i mentioned in my edit.)

Comment: You need to walk through the entire process you used to created `mybuild_img`, and/or add some more debugging to the build. I created a container from golang:1.5.1, then used it to build and copy a binary to a volume on OSX, and got an ELF binary as expected.

Comment: Not sure what changed between yesterday and today, but i just went to run the commands again to copy them here to show exactly what i was doing and now i am getting an ELF binary. Wish I knew what was wrong yesterday but at least it is working as expected now. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are still binding to some C libraries. This is a common problem when moving a Go executable to a super minimal container. You can roll these bound libraries into your executable by changing 
`go build`
 to
`CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -a -installsuffix cgo -o main .` You can find some more information on this problem and how it relates to minimal docker builds at [Codeship's blog](https://blog.codeship.com/building-minimal-docker-containers-for-go-applications/).

Comment: This works great. Thanks for your help and sharing that link.

Comment: This does not "roll" any linked libraries into your executable. This uses a native go implementation when available (i.e. dns name resolution), or disables the functionality (i.e. user lookups and locating ssl certs on OSX)